# 'NHibernate.Mapping.Property' is not an attribute class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, c#-3.0, nhibernate-mapping

This code fails to compile with the error *'NHibernate.Mapping.Property' is not an attribute class*. Any ideas why?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DevExpress.Xpo;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate.Mapping;

namespace Test {

  public class User : IdentityItem {

    public string email;
    public string password;
    public string displayname;

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Property(IsLazy = true, IsOptional = true, Name = "admin_notes")]
    public string admin_notes { get; set; }

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because 'NHibernate.Mapping.Property' is not an attribute class.

Use 'NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property' instead.

Comment: or change/add using NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property and just use [Property(IsLaz...

Comment: is there a way to do this with NH3?

Comment: I think yes. I've not tested it, but I see no reason why it would not work

Comment: I would change the using to: NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes, and as Antony says... you then only have to specify [Property(etc...] as the attribute detail. You can also then use the simplest form of Attribute descriptors: [Class], [Set], [Key], [OneToMany], [ManytoOne], [Id], [Generator], etc. without the fully qualified prefix.